# Why does john force MinLen to 8 for wpapsk?

Tags: wpa2-psk

I'm trying to use [`john`](http://www.openwall.com/john/) to test wpa security. I want it to generate 10-character passwords, so I've added this to `john.conf`:

```
[Incremental:Test]
File = $JOHN/alnum.chr
MinLen = 10
MaxLen = 10
CharCount = 62
```

However, when I run `john --format=wpapsk --session=mysession --incremental=Test data`, it prints:

> Note: minimum length forced to 8

and still generates 8-character passwords. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> and still generates 8-character passwords. What am I missing?

**"incremental"** mode is limited to lengths up to 8 by default, at
compile time.

> How to deal with this ?

Download JTR source code

1. Now edit the src/params.h file - replace the following lines (around
   line 200):

> ```
> define CHARSET_MIN ' '
> define CHARSET_MAX 0x7E
> define CHARSET_LENGTH 8
> ```

```
with:
```

> ```
> define CHARSET_MIN ' '
> define CHARSET_MAX  0x7E
> define CHARSET_LENGTH 10
> ```

2. Then let's rebuild JtR with this modification:
3. And generate a new .chr file:

> ./john --make-charset=digits10.chr

Now you can define a new "incremental" mode:

```
[Incremental:Digits10] 
File = $JOHN/digits10.chr 
MinLen = 10 
MaxLen = 10 
CharCount = 64
```

hope this will work for you

Comment: Alright , please check the output of *./john -i=alnumspace.chr --stdout | head -1000000 | tail* and *./john -i=alnum.chr --stdout | head -1000000 | tail*

Comment: provide it here too

Comment: `"incremental" mode is limited to lengths up to 8 by default, at compile time.` — this is no longer true since [1.8.0](http://www.openwall.com/lists/announce/2013/05/30/1)

Comment: `john -i=alnumspace.chr --stdout | head -1000000 | tail
Unknown option: "-i=alnumspace.chr"`